# Dynamically populate a select field in Wordpress ACF from a database table

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Right i got a lot of criticism for this question so i will rewrite it.
I am using Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) in Wordpress to to build my forms. My particular problem is that in a Select i do not want to pre-populate the field but dynamically fill it at run time from a table in the database.

To build a form group you use ACF's gui to create and define a Form Group, which has one or more Form Fields in it. One this is defined you export the working code and then use this code when the application runs. The exported code is an array of arrays and subarrays that define the characteristics of the Form and cannot contain dynamic code.

As an aside if the items in a field are Post Types then ACF lets you point to and filter by the Post Types giving a sort of Select field. However i do not want to make this particular data a Post Type.

An example of the created code for a hard wired Select Field is as follows.

```
acf_add_local_field_group(array (
'key' => 'group_568d1e1d7e7fd',
'title' => 'Course Information',
'fields' => array (
    array (
        'key' => 'field_568d1e2d97b99',
        'label' => 'Accrediting Body',
        'name' => 'joltle_course_accrediting_body',
        'type' => 'select',
        'instructions' => '',
        'required' => 1,
        'conditional_logic' => 0,
        'wrapper' => array (
            'width' => '',
            'class' => '',
            'id' => '',
        ),
        'choices' => array (
            0 => '',
            1093 => 'British Institute of Cleaning Science',
            1094 => 'British Oxygen Corporation (BOC)',
            1095 => 'CardianBCT',
            1096 => 'Chartered Institute of Environmental Health',
            1097 => 'Critical Care Institute Manchester',
        ),
        'default_value' => '0',
        'allow_null' => 0,
        'multiple' => 0,
        'ui' => 0,
        'ajax' => 0,
        'placeholder' => '',
        'disabled' => 0,
        'readonly' => 0,
    ),
    array (
```

It is the 'choices' array that i wish to replace dynamically.

An example of the table and the data i wish to use is as follows.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `counties `;
```

CREATE TABLE `counties` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `county` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=91 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `counties` (`id`, `county`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Bath and North East Somerset'),
    (2, 'Bedford'),
    (3, 'Blackburn with Darwen'),
    (4, 'Blackpool'),
    (5, 'Bournemouth'),
    (6, 'Bracknell Forest'),
    (7, 'Brighton & Hove');

xx

Comment: You're going to need to share your table code, at the very least...

Comment: Off topic - Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Off topic. Sorry did you read the question? i did not ask for a recommendation or a book or for someone to google the problem for me i asked if someone had solved this problem and if so to point me to the code. There is no way that this question could be answered in an opinionated way. Populating a select filed from a database query must either work or not and surely cannot be an 'opinion'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is in the ACF docs found at http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/dynamically-populate-a-select-fields-choices/

```
function acf_some_field( $field ) {
    //Change this to whatever data you are using.
    $data_from_database = array('key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2');

    $field['choices'] = array();

    //Loop through whatever data you are using, and assign a key/value
    foreach($data_from_database as $field_key => $field_value) {
        $field['choices'][$field_key] = $field_value;
    }
    return $field;
}
add_filter('acf/load_field/name=what_you_need', 'acf_some_field');
```

Comment: This link does not appear to solve the problem. The data is not called from a database table but from an option page which is not what i am looking for.

Comment: You're right, it shows you how to create a select box using any dynamic data you choose. Ill update my answer, even though you still haven't provided an example of the code you're trying to use.

Comment: Now that you've added some code examples, you should see that my answer is still exactly what you're looking for. Unless you're hoping for someone to write querys for you...

Comment: Sorry it took a while for the penny to drop. What is not that clear (at least to me) is instantiate the item and then modify it. Thanks.